# Some weird glitching of the graphical interface

Tags: unity

My Ubuntu is almost unuseable right now. the top and left bars disappeared and the keyboard shortcuts are not working. I am running Ubuntu 14. By opening a folder from the desktop I am able to navigate trough the file system.

The OS showed some problems before I restarted it. I installed Oracle VirtualBox, but it disappeared. Then the Software Center disappeared too.

I can still open applications, but I can't move some of them around the screen.

Is there anything I can do about that, or I shall reinstall the OS?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Ask Ubuntu, Have you try a lighter distribution of Ubuntu? I'm not sure what the specs are for your machine. Try Lubuntu http://lubuntu.net/ it might be a better choice for the machine in question. If you can show us what the message was when you restarted we might have a better answer for you

Comment: Thank you, Rob. Is this really a problem with the PC? I have a NVidea Quadro FX 1800, 4 GB of RAM and I'm not sure what CPU. It's no much but ubuntu has been running quite smooth in the past month.

Comment: When I think about it, I have a SSD that might have broken although it's pretty new.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, at that point I personally would reformat the disk and perform a clean install. Usually this is much faster & easier that spending hours troubleshooting your system. Hopefully you have your data backed up on an external drive, or copied to DVDs..

There is great software for backing up your system called Clonezilla:

http://clonezilla.org/

With this you simply copy your drive to an external drive, and restore when needed.

You can download here:

http://clonezilla.org/downloads/download.php?branch=stable

I hope that helps.